# Efficient deletion in Fenwick tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees

Suppose there is an array of nonzero integer values `A[n]`, which has a Fenwick tree representation `F[n]`. The most simplistic way to delete `A[index]` and update the values accordingly in `F[]` would be to perform `update(index, -A[index])`, then set `A[index]=0`. However, I could imagine that after a few deletes, the tree would be quite inefficient with all the 0s floating around.

We could compress the tree at each deletion by shifting the values down in `A[]` after `A[index]=0` and rebuilding `F[index:n]` by referencing `A`. However, this solution is worst case `O(nlogn)` time, and I feel like if there was a way to rebuild `F[index:n]` using values in `F[]`, this could be much more efficient. Unfortunately, the literature online seems a bit sparse on the deletion front. Any ideas?

Comment: You can construct `F(A)` in linear time, right?  Can you then amortize away all the deletions?  If there are $n$ deletions, you build a new tree without the deleted elements, charge the deleted elements.